# Need tooltip on mouseover in three.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, three.js

I'm loading object like [this demo](https://codepen.io/kiranm/pen/WNojOdX), where I want to show tooltip / infobox on mouse over that particular part. (Like on clicking button top, I want to show tooltip on top of the box). I tried these examples, but not working with my obj.

[Example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39177205/threejs-tooltip/54438811) [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117073/add-a-tooltip-to-a-div)

I tried like

```
 cube.name = "top cube";
  cube.getObjectbyname = "top cube obj";
  scene.add(cube); // add cube to the scene
```

I'm new to three.js and angular material. So I don't know how to add tooltip. How can I fix it? I don't know how to link my button and object top / left / right.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but I think this has already been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47297794/how-to-overlay-html-text-buttons-on-three-js

Comment: @TomBonynge: This is different, i need tooltip on box, not popup.. but thanks i got idea from this :-)

Answer (score 2):

[This example](https://threejs.org/examples/#css2d_label) features tooltips via the [CSS2DRenderer](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer) module, but they are always-on and synced to objects' positions.

If you want them to only appear on hover, you will have to selectively toggle them via a [Raycaster](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster) (sample code included in docs).

Below is an example of the combined techniques ([Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/css3d-tooltips-three-2l9v5?file=index.js)) with a single, shared label that moves and updates to hovered elements in your scene:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  cursor: grab;
  display: block;
}

canvas:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}

.hovered {
  cursor: help;
}

.label {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 2px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import {
    WebGLRenderer,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Scene,
    BoxGeometry,
    MeshNormalMaterial,
    Mesh,
    Vector3,
    Box3,
    Raycaster,
    Vector2,
  } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/build/three.module.js';
  import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
  import {
    CSS2DRenderer,
    CSS2DObject,
  } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.125.2/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer.js';

  // Boilerplate
  const { innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;

  const renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true, antialias: true });
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(2);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const camera = new PerspectiveCamera(70, innerWidth / innerHeight, 0.1, 10);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;

  const scene = new Scene();

  const geometry = new BoxGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  const material = new MeshNormalMaterial();
  const mesh = new Mesh(geometry, material);
  mesh.name = 'mesh';
  scene.add(mesh);

  // Setup labels
  const labelRenderer = new CSS2DRenderer();
  labelRenderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px';
  labelRenderer.domElement.style.pointerEvents = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement);

  const labelDiv = document.createElement('div');
  labelDiv.className = 'label';
  labelDiv.style.marginTop = '-1em';
  const label = new CSS2DObject(labelDiv);
  label.visible = false;
  scene.add(label);

  // Track mouse movement to pick objects
  const raycaster = new Raycaster();
  const mouse = new Vector2();

  window.addEventListener('mousemove', ({ clientX, clientY }) => {
    const { innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;

    mouse.x = (clientX / innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(clientY / innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
  });

  // Handle window resize
  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    const { innerWidth, innerHeight } = window;

    renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  });

  renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
    controls.update();

    // Pick objects from view using normalized mouse coordinates
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    const [hovered] = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

    if (hovered) {
      // Setup label
      renderer.domElement.className = 'hovered';
      label.visible = true;
      labelDiv.textContent = hovered.object.name;

      // Get offset from object's dimensions
      const offset = new Vector3();
      new Box3().setFromObject(hovered.object).getSize(offset);

      // Move label over hovered element
      label.position.set(
        hovered.object.position.x,
        offset.y / 2,
        hovered.object.position.z
      );
    } else {
      // Reset label
      renderer.domElement.className = '';
      label.visible = false;
      labelDiv.textContent = '';
    }

    // Render scene
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    // Render labels
    labelRenderer.render(scene, camera);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Cody Bennett: I ll surely try this. Thanks for your time